# Efficient implementation of bidirectional map between 64bit and 32bit unsigned integers

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, opengl, containers

Imagine we have 2 machines named: Alice and Bob. Alice supports operations with 64 bit unsigned integers while Bob operates with 32bit unsigned integers only.

Bob sends Alice request to create a task. For each task Alice assigns unique ID that is random but unique 64bit unsigned integer. Bob can create up to 2^32 tasks.

I need to add an ability for Bob to be able to delete tasks by ID. Therefore I need to set up a proxy that will substitute 64bit units with 32bit uints when message goes from Alice to Bob and restore 64bit uint from 32bit uint when message goes in opposite direction.

The problem is that I need to make conversion very efficient, I only have ~10MB of RAM to do this.
Is there any container that already solves that issue?

**Update**

The community asked for a clarification and the only way to clarify it is to describe real-world situation.

So, I'm working on OpenGL translator libraries that are part of the AOSP. In summary it allows to move rendering of Android system (e.g. running inside the VM) to the host system for acceleration reasons.
It's done by streaming all OpenGL commands (forth and back) from Target (Android) to Host (i.e. Win8 64bit).

OpenGL objects are represented as handles which are of type `GLuint` or `unsigned int`. Therefore size of the object and allowed values depend on whether system is 32bit or 64bit.

Since most Android systems are 32bit and most host systems are 64bit, the problem arise: in request of creating OpenGL object from Android, Host can create handle with value that cannot be represented as 32bit value. However, Android cannot ask for more than `2^32 - 1` objects for obvious reasons.

The only solution that came to my mind is to set up the proxy that will map 64bit handles to 32bit and vice versa.

The concrete piece of code that creates problem: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/master/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/include/GLcommon/GLutils.h line 47.

**Update 2**

After exploring the problem a little bit further I've found that it's not an issue of GLuint (as noted by @KillianDS). However it's still issue of OpenGL.

There are functions that return pointers, not GLuint handles. E.g. [eglCreateContext](http://www.khronos.org/registry/egl/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/eglCreateContext.html).
I need to find a way to exchange pointers between 64bit Host and 32bit Target.

**Update 3**

Finally I figured out that this concrete crash is not related to transition of handles between 32bit and 64bit machines. It is a bug in the Target part of translator that calls wrong function (glVertexAttribPointerData) with wrong argument.

Comment: Why do you need to convert. Just ensure that you're using platform independent types such as `int32_t`, `int64_t` so that the data is the same size.

Comment: I'd suggest that both sides use a 32-bit ID.  Or simply have Bob treat two adjacent 32-bit values as a 64-bit value.  If for some strange reason neither of those is possible then you need a hashtable to translate.

Comment: In case you haven't noticed, there is NO injective function `{0..2^64-1} -> {0..2^32-1}`. It's easy to prove using the [pidgeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle). So what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: @Sean This example is completely artificial just to demonstrate requirements of the system.

Comment: @HotLicks Of course I need a hash table. The question is to find most efficient implementation for this case.

Comment: @NiklasB Indeed each task has random but unique value within the `{0..2^64 - 1}` range. But Bob can only ask for up to `2^32 - 1` tasks, therefore such map can exist (but not pre-generated) due to restrictions above.

Comment: It's not clear that a hashtable is what you really need, but if you think so, then you should study the various HT techniques and see which suits you best.

Comment: Ok, than why not just use a hash table and assign to the first increasing request the number 1, the second gets 2 etc. you get the pattern. Just store the original request number in an array, so you only need a hash table in one direction.

Comment: @HotLicks That's exactly the purpose of this question to see if there are any version of HT optimized for such conversions with a given data type.

Comment: @NiklasB. You mean I have to pre-create an array of `4 * 2^32` bytes?

Comment: Well if you really expect so many queries? But you can also grow it over time since you assign numbers increasingly from 0 upwards.

Comment: I cannot predict neither how many queries there will be nor the pattern, so I should be ready for the worst case.

Comment: A hashtable _able to store 2^32 elements_ (condition 1) and _fitting in 10MB of RAM_ (condition 2)? Good luck. That wouldn't even work for bit-sized data types, and assuming that pointers have zero size.

Comment: @Damon Ok, you catched me :) Indeed, eventually it will grow up and in the worst case there is no chance to fit in 10MB. There won't be so that many elements at one time, but they will be created/queried/deleted very often and 64bit values can be random (uniform distribution).

Comment: @HotLicks I'm asking for advice for a concrete implementation of bidirectional map for the very concrete situation. I hope someone faced the same problem and can share his experience.

Comment: If the keys are indeed reasonably well-distributed random values, make a power-of-two hashtable (whatever size, 2^16 or 2^20) and put each key into the cell with the 64-bit key modulo your table size (the compiler will optimize the modulo to logical AND). That is all you need to do, apart from a solid hash table implementation. There is no way to make it any better. Calculating a hash is useless if the input is already random. You could for example use `std::unordered_map` with a static_cast-hash (though that one will not be fixed size).

Comment: @Damon Sounds like a reasonable approach. Maybe you know of good multi-level hash table implementation in C/C++? I want to have multiple levels in case distribution is not uniform.

Comment: I updated the question, hope it makes sense now.

Comment: Are you actually sure gluint is 64-bit on your host? Afaik gluint has to be 32 bits, no matter the platform.

Comment: You do realize that exchanging pointers between different machines (even different processes) is _totally meaningless_, and that pointers returned by functions like `glCreateContext` and `glGetProcAddress` etc. are _almost guaranteed_ **not** to be kind-of-random or even unique? Storing such pointers in a hash map is equally meaningless.

Comment: @Damon Exchanging pointers is not meaningless. Remember that Target only uses this values to pass back to the Host to call functions it needs. And for Host these pointers are meaningful. They are guaranteed to be unique, because 2 objects cannot share the same time.

Comment: What if the host runs 2 OpenGL applications? It's almost guaranteed that OpenGL gives you similar or identical pointers (or identifiers such as object names) in both of them. Given the naked "number", it's impossible to tell where it came from or where it is valid. It might be valid in both processes. Or in one, or in none.

Comment: Other scenario: What if the host runs one application that creates two contexts? Most object handles will, again, probably be identical, but they may mean something different in the respective other context. And given a simple GLint name you can't tell.

Comment: @Damon Host is the source and sink for handles/pointers, while Target is an operator who asks to do whatever it needs and uses pointers and handles (which it gets from the Host) only for reference. The problem is that I cannot safely bypass this reference numbers due to different sizes of pointers on 32bit and 64bit architectures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `table 2.2` in the [latest core OpenGL spec](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec44.core.pdf) a uint in OpenGL should always be 32 bits in width (the spec is about the same for ES). All OpenGL names/handles are as far as I know (and you also say in your question) `uint`'s. So, it should be 32 bit on both your host and target.

Note that it is exactly because the actual bit width of `unsigned int` might differ between platforms that `OpenGL` has its own types that should conform to the spec.

## Update

If the remaining handles are really only contexts and other window-system calls I'd keep it simple because we're not talking frequent operations, nor a huge amount of handles. These kind of operations are usually not done more than once per OpenGL application per GPU, which is likely 1 on any mobile phone. I think the easiest solution of all would be to use an array. Pseudocode

```
class context_creator
{
    std::array<EGLContext, 1000> context_map; //8KB
public:
    context_creator() : context_map{} {}
    uint32_t allocate(...) {
        for(unsigned i = 0; i < context_map.size(); i++) {
            if(!context_map[i]) {
                context_map[i] = eglCreateContext(...);
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
    void deallocate(uint32_t handle) {
        eglDeleteContext(context_map[handle]);
        context_map[handle] = 0;
    }
    //Has to be called in every function where a context is a parameter.
    EGLContext translate(uint32_t handle) const {
        return context_map[handle];
    }
}
```

One note, this won't work if `0` is a valid name for a context. I really don't know for WGL, but probably it's not. The advantage of this is that while the allocate isn't the fastest algorithm ever, the translate is `O(1)` and that's what most likely will be called most often.

Of course, variations exists:

- You can use a more dynamic container (e.g. `vector`) instead of fixed size.
- You can use a hashtable (like `std::map`) and just generate a unique index per call. This consumes more memory as you have to store the index also (it's imlicit in an array), but it solves the problem if `0` is a valid context name.

Comment: Please check Update 2.

Comment: @Kentzo that's a completely different issue as the number of those handles are usually in a complete different ballpark. I updated my answer with my idea about that.

Answer (score -1):

The uint in OpenGL should be 4 bytes i.e. 32 bits always in width so handles/names should be 32 bit on both your target and host

Comment: OpenGL assigns the numbers for you, you don't get to pick them yourself.